# How does Django store the reference of media file (or images) in database

Tags: django, database, django-models, reference, media

My question is not How to store file/image or fetch/show/access them into the templates.

My question is one level deeper, I want to know

When we define a file/image field in Django model, and upload a file to it which store the file/image into media root. Then we access through modelInstance.file.url . So does Django stores url of file/image or name or just location in media root ( .url will give this appended to media url) into the database.

I just want to know what reference does Django save into database for media file??

Comment: probably the file path and file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

generally it saves the location of file, inside media root. you can see in database also.

here's official docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/